# Efficient averaging (moving average)

Tags: c#, algorithm, moving-average

I have a stream of data (integers) with given (constant) frequency. From time to time I need to compute different averages (predefined). I am looking for solution to do it fast and efficient.

Assumptions:

- Sampling rate is constant (predefined) and might be something between 125-500 SPS
- Averages I need to compute are predefined and it might me one average or many (for example only last 200ms average or last 250ms and last 500ms). There might be many averages but they are predefined!
- At any time I need to be able to compute current average (real time)

What I have right now:

- I assume that in particular timeframe there will be always the same amount of data. So having frequency 100SPS I assume that one second contain exactly 100 values
- Queue with constant length is created (something like buffer)
- For EVERY defined average, Sum variable is created
- Every time new sample arrive I place it on the queue.
- Every time I have new sample in the queue I add its value to the every Sum variables I have and also remove value of element which is out of the window (based on position in Queue)
- Once I need to compute average I just take the particular Sum variable and divide it by number of elements this Sum should contain

To give you more better insight there is a code which I have right now:

```
public class Buffer<T> : LinkedList<T>
{
    private readonly int capacity;

    public bool IsFull => Count >= capacity;

    public Buffer(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (Count == capacity)
        {
            RemoveFirst();
        }
        AddLast(item);
    }
}


public class MovingAverage
{
    private readonly Buffer<float> Buffer;
    private static readonly object bufferLock = new object();
    public Dictionary<string, float> Sums { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Counts { get; private set; }

    public MovingAverage(List<int> sampleCounts, List<string> names)
    {
        if (sampleCounts.Count != names.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong Moving Averages parameters");
        }
        Buffer = new Buffer<float>(sampleCounts.Max());

        Sums = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        Counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            Sums[names[i]] = 0;
            Counts[names[i]] = sampleCounts[i];
        }
    }


    public void ProcessAveraging(float val)
    {
        lock (bufferLock)
        {
            if (float.IsNaN(val))
            {
                val = 0;
            }
            foreach (var keyVal in Counts.OrderBy(a => a.Value))
            {
                Sums[keyVal.Key] += val;
                if (Buffer.Count >= keyVal.Value)
                {
                    Sums[keyVal.Key] -= Buffer.ElementAt(Buffer.Count - keyVal.Value);
                }

            }
            Buffer.Enqueue(val);
        }
    }

    public float GetLastAverage(string averageName)
    {
        lock (bufferLock)
        {
            if (Buffer.Count >= Counts[averageName])
            {
                return Sums[averageName] / Counts[averageName];
            }
            else
            {
                return Sums[averageName] / Buffer.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works really nice and is fast enough but in real world having 100 SPS doesnt really mean you will always have 100 samples in 1 second. Sometimes its 100, sometimes 99, sometimes 101. Computing these averages is critical for my system and 1 sample more or less could change a lot. Thats why I need a real timer telling me whether sample is already out of moving-average window or not.

The idea with adding timestamp to every sample seems to be promising

Comment: Stack doesn't sound like the right data structure - queue seems more appropriate. As for the time thing, could you not store a time stamp with each sample and then, as new data comes in and is added, remove (and subtract) the ones that are too old?

Comment: The stack is the right method.  You need to add a time of arrival to the list so you can accurately average the time.

Comment: I too think it should be a queue, not a stack, each element should have a date and you remove ones that are too old. No need to re-sum the entire queue all the time either - make it so the queue constantly tracks the sum of items it has (removal causes a total decrement, addition causes a total add) as well as the count then you can calc the avg quickly

Comment: Sure, queue is probably better, thank you! Good idea with timestamp, I didnt even consider it. Regarding recalculating sum - I didnt write it but I need to calculate several sums for several different time intervals (averaging 200ms, averaging 500ms, averaging 1sec etc)

Comment: Do you really need the _average from last 2sec_ ?  The average of the last 500 samples would be so much easier. For an UI the difference should be moot.

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I updated my qeustion and added  more details. Sorry for not doing it at the begining but to be honest I didnt expect much response

Comment: @HenkHolterman I need to compute average from last seconds/miliseconds and not a single sample more

Comment: Check this blog out https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-simple-moving-average-calculator-in-csharp-1-a-simple-moving-average-calculator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of answers here.. Might as well add another one :)

This one might need some minor debugging for "off by one" etc - I didn't have a real dataset to work with so perhaps treat it as pseudocode

It's like yours: there's a buffer that is circular - give it enough capacity to hold N samples where N is enough to inspect your moving averages - 100 SPS and want to inspect 250ms I think you'll need at least 25, but we aren't short on space so you could make it more

```
struct Cirray
{
    long _head;
    TimedFloat[] _data;

    public Cirray(int capacity)
    {
        _head = 0;
        _data = new TimedFloat[capacity];
    }

    public void Add(float f)
    {
        _data[_head++%_data.Length] = new TimedFloat() { F = f };
    }

    public IEnumerable<float> GetAverages(int[] forDeltas)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        long start = _head - 1;
        long now = _data[start].T;
        int whichDelta = 0;

        for (long idx = start; idx >= 0 && whichDelta < forDeltas.Length; idx--)
        {
            if (_data[idx % _data.Length].T < now - forDeltas[whichDelta])
            {
                yield return (float)(sum / (start - idx));
                whichDelta++;
            }

            sum += _data[idx % _data.Length].F;
        }
    }
}

struct TimedFloat
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern void GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out long filetime);


    private float _f;
    public float F { get => _f;
        set {
            _f = value;
            GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out long x);
            T = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(x).Ticks;
        }
    }
    public long T;

}
```

The normal DateTime.UtcNow isn't very precise - about 16ms - so it's probably no good for timestamping data like this if youre saying that even one sample could throw it off. Instead we can make it so we get the ticks equivalent of the high resolution timer, if your system supports it (if not, you might have to change system, or abuse a StopWatch class into giving a higher resolution supplement) and we're timestamping every data item.

I thought about going to the complexity of maintaining N number of constantly moving pointers to various tail ends of the data and dec/incrementing N number of sums - it could still be done (and you clearly know how) but your question read like you'd probably call for the averages infrequently enough that an N sums/counts solution would spend more time maintaining the counts than it would to just run through 250 or 500 floats every now and then and just add them up. GetAverages as a result takes an array of *ticks* (10 thousand per ms) of the ranges you want the data over, e.g. `new[] { 50 * 10000, 100 * 10000, 150 * 10000, 200 * 10000, 250 * 10000 }` for 50ms to 250ms in steps of 50, and it starts at the current head and sums backwards until the point where it's going to break a time boundary (and this might be the off-by-one bit) whereupon it yields the average for that timespan, then resumes summing and counting (the count given by math of the start minus the current index) for the next time span.. I think I understood right that you want e.g. the "average over the last 50ms" and "average over the last 100ms", not "average for the recent 50ms" and "average for the 50ms before recent"

Edit:

Thought about it some more and did this:

struct Cirray
{
long _head;
TimedFloat[] _data;
RunningAverage[] _ravgs;

```
    public Cirray(int capacity)
    {
        _head = 0;
        _data = new TimedFloat[capacity];
    }

    public Cirray(int capacity, int[] deltas) : this(capacity)
    {
        _ravgs = new RunningAverage[deltas.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < deltas.Length; i++)
            _ravgs[i] = new RunningAverage() { OverMilliseconds = deltas[i] };
    }

    public void Add(float f)
    {
        //in c# every assignment returns the assigned value; capture it for use later
        var addedTF = (_data[_head++ % _data.Length] = new TimedFloat() { F = f });

        if (_ravgs == null)
            return;

        foreach (var ra in _ravgs)
        {
            //add the new tf to each RA
            ra.Count++;
            ra.Total += addedTF.F;

            //move the end pointer in the RA circularly up the array, subtracting/uncounting as we go
            var boundary = addedTF.T - ra.OverMilliseconds; 
            while (_data[ra.EndPointer].T < boundary) //while the sample is timed before the boundary, move the
            {
                ra.Count--; 
                ra.Total -= _data[ra.EndPointer].F;
                ra.EndPointer = (ra.EndPointer + 1) % _data.Length; //circular indexing
            }
        }

    }

    public IEnumerable<float> GetAverages(int[] forDeltas)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        long start = _head - 1;
        long now = _data[start].T;
        int whichDelta = 0;

        for (long idx = start; idx >= 0 && whichDelta < forDeltas.Length; idx--)
        {
            if (_data[idx % _data.Length].T < now - forDeltas[whichDelta])
            {
                yield return (float)(sum / (start - idx));
                whichDelta++;
            }

            sum += _data[idx % _data.Length].F;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<float> GetAverages() //from the built ins
    {
        foreach (var ra in _ravgs)
        {
            if (ra.Count == 0)
                yield return 0;
            else
                yield return (float)(ra.Total / ra.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Absolutely haven't tested it, but it embodies my thinking in the comments

Comment: HI, really nice solution! I already used some of the solutions people provided but this one seems to be the the most promising :)
Regarding running pointers - I think its a little bit better since I have also 30sec and 60sec averages what gives me up to 15 thousand of samples  (in given timeframe) and the average is computed more or less every 100-200ms.

Comment: In my system there are about 20-25 different streams/Ciarrays (with 250 SPS) and for each one I am computing 2-3 different averages. I thought its better to keep many Sums in one Ciarray object but thinking about it now maybe its a little bit too complex and its better to have many Ciarray with only one Sum each

Comment: btw, whats the benefit of using structr over class in Ciarray ?

Comment: Yes, for a scenario where the length of time you're averaging over far exceeds the frequency with which you request the average, running pointers should be more efficient - I was imagining that it was an "up to 250ms of samples, every second" so moving eg 5 pointers every time a sample is taken is 5000 movements compared to 250 movements to calc the average, once a second (i think!). Of course calcing the average fully every time it's requested allows quick variation of the intervals - you could do it with moving pointers too I guess, if youre prepared to move them either way ..

Comment: ..from their current location, if the interval changes. In terms of "3 ciarray with one avg each" vs "1 cirray with 3 avg" - do whatever is easiest to program, so long as it can cope with the extra demand for memory (with the 3 cirray approach you're storing the same data 3 times so you can have a single running pointer, with the 1 cirray and 3 pointers you simply have the headache of moving the pointers. It shouldnt be too hard, you just keep your pointers in an array and when you're done moving one, you're onto the next. It's probably more efficient to move the pointers one step at a time..

Comment: ..rather than try something clever like binary searching for their next location, because realistically you're moving them on every sample coming in and most the time it means they will only be moving one or two places each. If you can burn the space and it makes sense to you to just have a cirray with one tail pointer and every sample add causes the tail to move until moving it would mean it's timed-out then that's the start, and I think you'll pretty quickly see that upgrading it from one variable to a loop over set of variables is actually trivial. struct v class prob no difference here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a linked list I would fall back to some internal functions as array copy. In this answer I included a possible rewrite for your buffer class. Taking over the idea to keep a sum at every position.

This buffer keeps track of all the sums but in order to do that it needs to sum up every item with the new value. Based on the frequency you need to get that average it might be better to sum up when you need it and only keep the individual values.

In any way I just wanted to point out how you could do it with Array.Copy

```
public class BufferSum
{
    private readonly int _capacity;
    private readonly int _last;
    private float[] _items;

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public bool IsFull => Count >= _capacity;

    public BufferSum(int capacity)
    {
        _capacity = capacity;
        _last = capacity - 1;
        _items = new float[_capacity];
    }

    public void Enqueue(float item)
    {
        if (Count == _capacity)
        {
            Array.Copy(_items, 1, _items, 0, _last);
            _items[_last] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Count++;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < Count; i ++)
        {
            _items[i] += item;
        }
    }

    public float Avarage => _items[0] / Count;

    public float AverageAt(int ms, int fps)
    {
        var _pos = Convert.ToInt32(ms / 1000 * fps);
        return _items[Count - _pos] / _pos; 
    }
}
```

Additional be careful with the lock statement that will take a lot of time to.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of size 500, int counter `c`.

```
For every sample:
    summ -= A[c % 500]  //remove old value
    summ += sample 
    A[c % 500] = sample  //replace it with new value
    c++
    if needed, calculate
        average = summ / 500
```

Comment: This is a queue (as a roll-over array). It doesn't address the 2 second problem.

Comment: @Henk Holterman In the initial post I saw only `Sampling rate is constant ` so proposed the simplest method. Sentence about `Sometimes its 100, sometimes 99, sometimes 101.` has been added later

Answer (score 0):

You always want to remove the oldest element on one side of your sequence and add a new element at the other side of the sequence: you need a queue instead of a stack.

I think a round list will be faster: as long as you have not the maximum size, just add the elements, once you've got the maximum size, replace the oldest element.

This seems like a nice reusable class. Later we'll add the moving average part.

```
class RoundArray<T>
{
    public RoundArray(int maxSize)
    {
        this.MaxSize = maxSize;
        this.roundArray = new List<T>(maxSize);
    }

    private readonly int maxSize;
    private readonly List<T> roundArray;
    public int indexOldestItem = 0;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        // if list not full, just add
        if (this.roundArray.Count < this.maxSize)
            this.roundArray.Add(item);
        else
        {
            // list is full, replace the oldest item:
            this.roundArray[oldestItem] = item;
            oldestItem = (oldestItem + 1) % this.maxSize;
        } 

        public int Count => this.roundArray.Count;
        public T Oldest => this.roundArray[this.indexOldestItem];               
    }
}
```

To make this class useful, add methods to enumerate the data, starting at the oldest or the newest, consider to add other useful reusable methods. Maybe you should implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Maybe some private fields should have public properties.

Your moving average calculator will use this RoundArray. Whenever an item is added, and your roundArray is not full yet, the item is added to the sum and to the round array.

If the roundArray is full, then the item replaces the oldest item. You subtract the value of the OldestItem from the Sum, and add the new Item to the Sum.

```
class MovingAverageCalculator
{
    public MovingAverageCalculator(int maxSize)
    {
        this.roundArray = new RoundArray<int>(maxSize);
    }

    private readonly RoundArray<int> roundArray;
    private int sum = 0;

    private int Count => this.RoundArray.Count;
    private int Average => this.sum / this.Count;

    public voidAdd(int value)
    {
        if (this.Count == this.MaxSize)
        {
            // replace: remove the oldest value from the sum and add the new one
            this.Sum += value - this.RoundArray.Oldest;
        }
        else
        {
            // still building: just add the new value to the Sum
            this.Sum  += value;
        }
        this.RoundArray.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thats almost exactly what I have right now. I updated my question. Sorry for changing it after you spend your time on this! Nevertheless, It still assume that in a particular timeframe there will be always the same number of elements, what is something I try to avoid

Comment: You call it an array, and you use a list.. ?

Comment: That's what information hiding is all about: Thou shallst not know how I complete my Task! The difference between an array and a list is that the array has a fixed length.  My Round-whatever also has a fixed length. By using the word RoundArray I give the reader the information that I will not provide functionality to increase or decrease the number of elements: if at construction time you decide that I should have 10 elements, you can't make it 11 elements

Answer (score 0):

#### Cumulative sums.

Compute a series of cumulative sums<sup>1</sup> for every block of ~1000 or so elements. (Could be less however 500 or 1000 is not that much of a difference and this will be more comfortable) You want to hold every block as long as at least one element inside is relevant. Then it can be recycled.<sup>2</sup>

When you need your current sum and you are within one block, your desired sum is:
`block[max_index] - block[last_relevant_number]`.

For the case when you are at the borderline of two blocks **b1, b2** in this order, your desired sum is:
`b1[b1.length - 1] - b1[last_relevant_number] + b2[max_index]`

And we are done. The main advantage of this approach is that you don't need to know beforehands how many elements you want to keep and you can compute the result on the go.
You also don't need to handle the removal of the elements as you will naturally overwrite them when you recycle the segment - keeping the indices is all you need.

Example: let us have a constant timeseries `ts = [1,1,1, .... 1]`. The cumulative sums of the series will be `cumsum = [1,2,3 ... n]`. The sum from i-th to the j-th(inclusive) element of the ts will be cumsum[j] - cumsum[i - 1] = j - i - 1. For i = 5, j = 6 it will be 6 - 4 = 2 which is correct.

---

1 For array [1,2,3,4,5] these would be [1,3,6,10,15] - just for the sake of completeness. 
2 Since you mentioned ~500 elements, two blocks should be enough.

Comment: But it still doesnt solve that somehow I need to assume that in particular timeframe there will be always the same samples. I updated my questions, sorry for not writting all at the begining

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow: The cumulative sums can compute any "windowed sum" if you have enough values stored & precomputed. Where is the issue? If you have your timeframe, just use a binary search to find the last relevant element.

Comment: It assume that  having frequency 100SPS there will be always 100 samples in one second but in real life its not true. Thats why I need to have a timer which tells me exactly which samples are already out of the window

Comment: What about storing the samples as (sample, timestamp) and using the binary search to discard the irrelevant ones? e. g. if you had samples (1,1), (2,1), (3,1) ... (1,5),(1,5) ... and only 3rd, 4th and 5th seconds were relevant, you would search for the first 3rd second sample. Then you would its index & the cumulative sums to compute the sum & average.

Comment: Yes, thats something already suggested in one comment and probably the way to go :)